# Cant set origin for an element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am making a simple game in js which consists of a grid and some cells[image]

This is what it currently looks like and it works perfectly. The thing is that while making this I set the margin to 0 but I
would like to move the canvas to center. To do that, I got the margin from this function

```
var test = document.querySelector('.test');
var left_margin = window.getComputedStyle(test).getPropertyValue("margin- 
    left "); // returns margin e.g. '655px'
    left_margin = left_margin.match(/\d+/);
```

Then I made some changes in the whole thing to account for this offset but for some reason when I try to add the offset to the x-axis, it returns NaN. To make sure there wasnt some problem I performed some basic mathematical operations on this value and they worked. Can someone tell me what is going on with this? and also, is there a simple way to just redefine the origin for an element(a canvas in my case), to avoid this hassle?

Edit:
I dont understand this. When i simply do var a = blockWidth + 0;The game doesnt start and then do console.log(a) this also return NaN. and i get**(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'strokeStyle' of undefined)**

```
function grid(){
    var a = blockWidth + left_margin;
    var b = blockHeight;
    while (a != widthWin){
        drawLine(a, 0, a, heightWin, 1, 'gray');
        a += blockWidth;
    }
    while (b != heightWin){
        drawLine(left_margin, b, widthWin+left_margin, b, 1, 'gray');
        b += blockHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, how do you use `left_margin` you calculate in the first snippet? What is its relationship with grid function?

Comment: for the grid function, i need the X-axis value. Since the the margin was zero before, there was no need for adding that to the X-axis but now since there is margin from the left, i would need to add that value to the X-axis.

Comment: How `left_margin` is used inside grid function? I still see no relationship, can you post some code?

Comment: ````function grid(){
    var a = blockWidth + left_margin;
    var b = blockHeight;
    while (a != widthWin){
        drawLine(a, 0, a, heightWin, 1, 'gray');
        a += blockWidth;
    }
    while (b != heightWin){
        drawLine(0, b, widthWin, b, 1, 'gray');
        b += blockHeight;
    }
}````

Comment: sorry idk why the code formatting isnt working? im new to this

Comment: You can directly edit the question with the updated snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get with

```
left_margin = left_margin.match(/\d+/);
```

is an array `["655"]` not an int as you are assuming.

Therefore, you need to access its first element and parse it to a number before using it for doing any math:

```
left_margin = parseInt(left_margin.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```